# AS3 - Event listener that only fires once

Tags: actionscript-3, events, addeventlistener, dispatch

I'm looking for a way to add an EventListener which will automatically removes itself after the first time it fires, but I can't figure a way of doing this the way I want to.

I found this function ([here](http://code.google.com/p/asphalt2/source/browse/trunk/asphalt2/src/asphalt2/util/EventUtil.as?r=457)) :

```
public class EventUtil
{
    public static function addOnceEventListener(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher,eventType:String,listener:Function):void
    {
         var f:Function = function(e:Event):void
         {
              dispatcher.removeEventListener(eventType,f);
              listener(e);
          }
          dispatcher.addEventListener(eventType,f);
    }
}
```

But instead of having to write :

```
EventUtil.addOnceEventListener( dispatcher, eventType, listener );
```

I would like to use it the usual way :

```
dispatcher.addOnceEventListener( eventType, listener );
```

Has anybody got an idea of how this could be done?
Any help would be greatly apprecitated.

---

*(I know that Robert Penner's [Signals](http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) can do this, but I can't use them since it would mean a lot of code rewriting that I can't afford for my current project)*

Comment: Try using the [Signals Library](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/wiki).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find the cleanest way without using statics or messing up your code with noise is to defining a global function (in a file called removeListenerWhenFired.as) like so:

```
package your.package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    public function removeListenerWhenFired(callback:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false):Function
    {
        return function (event:Event):void
        {
            var eventDispatcher:IEventDispatcher = IEventDispatcher(event.target)
            eventDispatcher.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee, useCapture)
            callback(event)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can listen for events like so:

```
import your.package.removeListenerWhenFired

// ... class definition

    sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICKED, 
        removeListenerWhenFired(
            function (event:MouseEvent):void {
                ... do something
            }
        )
    )
```

Comment: no problem ;) closures are indeed very handy. I'm building a whole bag full of closure and global function tricks, seeing where it'll all go.

Comment: How would you manually remove such a listener, since the listener you're adding is an anonymous function? If you can't remove it manually then sooner or later you'll be chewin on a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it, but you could just turn the EventUtil static method into a standard method and extend the class in your object.

```
public class OnceEventDispatcher
{
    public function addOnceEventListener(eventType:String,listener:Function):void
    {
         var f:Function = function(e:Event):void
         {
              this.removeEventListener(eventType,f);
              listener(e);
          }
          this.addEventListener(eventType,f);
    }
}

public class Example extends OnceEventDispatcher
{


}

var ex:Example = new Example();
ex.addOnceEventListener(type, func);
```

Comment: I can't use inheritance since AS3 doesn't allow multiple inheritance, and most of my classes are already extending another one. I thought of putting this function in an external .as file that I'll include in all my classes, but I was wondering if there was a nicer way to actually do this.

Comment: I also could add the function to the UIComponent class directly in the Flex SDK ; that would solve my problem, but it's even uglier =/

Answer (score 1):

```
functionadd.addEventListener(COMPLETE,functionremove);

functionremove()
{
    runevent();
    functionadd.removeEventListener(COMPLETE,functionremove);
}
function runevent()
{
   trace('Hello');
}
```